# Bad Request ("error reading build args: json: cannot unmarshal number into Go value of type string")

Tags: python, docker, python-docker

Using docker python library,

```
    UID = USER_ID = os.getuid()
    GROUP_ID = os.getgid()
    USER = getpass.getuser()
    HOME = "~"
    DIR = os.getcwd()
    DOCKER_GID = execute_shell_command('"$(stat -c "%g" /var/run/docker.sock)"', log_path)
    VERSION = "latest"
    BASE_DOCKER = "ubuntu:20.04"

    assert os.path.isfile(dockerfile_path)

    build_args = {
        "UID": UID,
        "DOCKER_GID": DOCKER_GID,
        "UNAME": USER,
        "VER": VERSION,
        "BASE_IMAGE": BASE_DOCKER,
    }  

client = client = docker.from_env()
client.images.build(fileobj=dockerfile, buildargs=build_args)
```

Getting

```
Bad Request ("error reading build args: json: cannot unmarshal number into Go value of type string")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not Googleable, so posting for future readers

Answer was found [here](https://github.com/UofT-EcoSystem/rlscope/blob/master/run_docker.py)

Convert numbers in `build_args` to strings to avoid this [undocumented](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/images.html) error:

```
 build_args = {k: str(v) for k, v in {
        "UID": UID,
        "DOCKER_GID": DOCKER_GID,
        "UNAME": USER,
        "VER": VERSION,
        "BASE_IMAGE": BASE_DOCKER,
    }.items()}
```